# How to fake my laptop GPU?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have GTX 1650 4GB GDDR5 in my laptop, but I want to test Minecraft Windows 10 Edition with RTX, but it disallows me to do it. How can I fake my GPU or it's impossible?

Answer (score 9):

**You can't**. Minecraft RTX relies on features exclusive to Nvidia RTX 2000 and 3000 series GPUs. Any other GPU will simply be unable to run it even if you were able to trick the system into thinking you met the minimum spec.

Comment: 25 seconds apart, WOW

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is impossible.

This raytracing is an new GPU rendering addition that requires specialized hardware, as in specific RT cores found on the graphics card itself. It will NOT work on any hardware without those cores, and even if it were possible to trick the game into believing your GPU has raytracing support and to force your GPU into running the related calculations it would greatly lower your framerate to the point of unplayability.

Comment: "Raytracing is an entirely new GPU technology", raytracing is actually a very old technology. The idea was described in the 16th century, implemented on computers by the 70s (possibly earlier), and used extensively by the movie and gaming industry for computer generated (pre-rendered) movie clips. You're probably thinking about Nvidia RTX.

Comment: @Nolonar It is new as a GPU technology though. AFAIK no GPUs before the first RTX series supported real time raytracing.

Comment: Yes, and RTX is the new technology that allowed us to run an old technology in real time. Doesn't change the fact that raytracing is still old, and RTX is what's new.